# When utilizing a for loop what does each argument specify exactly?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I'm new to learning Python and have a clarifying question regarding for loops.

For instance:

```
dictionary_a = {"A": "Apple", "B": "Ball", "C": "Cat"}
dictionary_b = {"A": "Ant", "B": "Basket", "C": "Carrot"}
temp = ""
for k_a, v_a in dictionary_a.items():
    temp = dictionary_b[k_a]
    dictionary_b[k_a] = v_a
    dictionary_a[k_a] = temp
```

How exactly is `k_a` run through the interpreter? I understand `v_a in dictionary_a.items()` as simply iterating through the sequence `in` whatever collection.

But when `for` loops have the syntax `for x, y in z` I don't quite understand what values `x`  takes with each iteration.

Hope I'm making some sense. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Try printing `dictionary_a.items()` without running the loop and understand the output you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when iterating over a `dict.items()`, it will return a 2 tuple, so when providing two variables in the for loop, each tuple elements will be assigned to it.

Here is another example to help you understand the mechanics:

```
coordinates = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]

for x, y, z in coordinates:
    print(x)
```

Edit: you can make even more complicated unpacking. For example, let's assume you are interested to collect only the first and last item in a long list, you can proceed as follow:

```
long_list = 'This is a very long list to process'.split()
first_item, *_, last_item = long_list
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can "Cast" multiple variables from another iterable variable.

Let's use this example:

```
>>> a, b = [1, 2]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

The above behavior is what is happening when you loop over a dictionary with the `dict.items()` method.

Here is an example of what is happening:

```
>>> a = {"abc":123, "def":456}
>>> a.items()
dict_items([('abc', 123), ('def', 456)])
>>> for i in a.items():
...   i
...
('abc', 123)
('def', 456)
>>>
```